# How to fetch values of json file using shell script?

Tags: json, shell

I have a sample json file shown below:

```
 {
  "component": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "key": "abc",
    "name": "project",
    "qualifier": "TRK",
    "measures": [
      {
        "metric": "ncloc",
        "value": "43"
      },
      {
        "metric": "bugs",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "blocker_violations",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "info_violations",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "critical_violations",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "vulnerabilities",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "major_violations",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "code_smells",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "minor_violations",
        "value": "0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "reliability_rating",
        "value": "1.0",
        "bestValue": true
      },
      {
        "metric": "security_rating",
        "value": "1.0",
        "bestValue": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From the above .json file I need to fetch metric and its respective value as : say   'bugs:0'. I do find related blogs but bit confused.

my usecase:
I want to read all metric values and if any of value is <> 0 then exit 1 is to be executed else exit 0. I tried below one just for one metric.

```
if [  jq -r '.component.measures[].info_violations.value'!= 0 ]
then 
exit 1
else
exit 0
```

The code isn't throwing any error, but I am sure that it is incorrect logic and just tried for single metric. Now I am clear with my use-case, I hope someone can help me.

I need to fetch all metrics and corresponding values for items in measures[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can use the following JQ filter to check if `any` of the values equals `0`:

```
.component.measures | any(.value == "0")
```

Thanks to [@Glenn](https://8%20mins%20ago) for pointing out `--exit-status`, this lets JQ exit with the status you'll need. So we can use that as `exit` value, using `$?`:

```
#!/bin/bash

jq --exit-status '.component.measures | any(.value == "0")' input
exit $?
```

---

###### [JqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/tnsRYASGcPH)

Comment: The `--exit-status` option will be useful here: `jq -e '.component.measures | all(.value == "0")' input; exit $?`

Comment: Thankyou both of you. But I am trying to run this shell script through git bash [hidden folder] where jq command is not priorly installed. Hence, getting 'jq' command not found error. I am checking on installing jq in my git bash. Meanwhile if there is any other alternative you are welcomed to suggest